# How to exclude unnecessary requests from JMeter log file in NonGUI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am running JMeter 4.0 r1823414.

In my test suite, I have the following structure:

[image]

When I run this TestPlan in non gui mode with the following command:

`.\jmeter -t $testplan -l $testlog -e -o $reportFolder`

I get a CSV file with all debug steps and requests (Authentication for example).
I am interested only in Query requests.
How can I exclude all requests from the CSV file and leave only Query requests in there?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I did wrong.
by providing `-l` with a file path, I created a listener for the whole test session:

> [**12.2 non-GUI (batch) test runs**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#batch)
>   When running in non-GUI mode, the -l flag can be used to create a top-level listener for the test run. This is in addition to any Listeners defined in the test plan. The configuration of this listener is controlled by entries in the file jmeter.properties as described in the previous section.

If I run `jmeter -n -t $testplan` i get just the logs from the listeners I have specified

Answer (score 0):

This is exact match for [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) jmeter plugin

> It should also filter queries that are not calls to the application but debug samplers or intermediate calculation samplers as beanshell samplers.

In your case you search for Query:

```
 jmeter\lib\ext\FilterResults.bat --output-file filteredout.csv --input-file inputfile.jtl --include-label-regex true --include-labels "Query.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude from CSV , then go for [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) as per @ser7294900 answer.

But if you only want to exclude in HTML report then :

- First apply Naming Convention on your Transaction Controllers by right clicking on them and selecting "Apply Naming Convention"

[image: Apply Naming Convention]
 - Second, use menu Help > "Export Transactions for report" and replace  this in user.properties

[image: Export Transactions for report]