# How do you make a threadGroup time not be taken in consideration of the total time

Tags: jmeter

I have the following scenario:

```
Thread group1 - this sends requests to a server (lots of threads and iterations)
    HTTP Request
Thread group2 - 1 thread 1 iterations
    JSR223 sampler (has a while loop which periodically check if a number is 0) and collects some times
```

The scenario ends when threadgroup 2 finishes

I run the above scenario using the non GUI mode and i am interested in the RPS. (as shown below 222.0/s), but only for the first threadGroup.

```
summary =  50002 in 00:03:29 =  222.0/s Avg:  4151 Min:    38 Max: 797601 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

Now, when the last threadGroup ends i will have:

```
summary =  50003 in 00:09:12 =   90.7/s Avg:  4136 Min:    38 Max: 797601 Err:     0 (0.00%)
```

The RPS is now low only because the last threadGroup takes very long to finish.

Is there any way the time from the last threadGroup can not be taken into consideration of the total time ? Or maybe another approach to this problem.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810486/how-to-exclude-unnecessary-requests-from-jmeter-log-file-in-nongui-mode/48810647#48810647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter` property in order to exclude your `JSR223 Sampler` from the report.

1. Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. The command to generate **FULL** results would look like:

   ```
   jmeter -g result.jtl -o ALL-RESULTS
   ```

   It will create `ALL-RESULTS` folder holding information on all the samplers
3. The command to generate results **WITHOUT JSR223 Sampler** would be:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter="^((?!JSR223 Sampler).)*$" -g result.jtl -o FILTERED-RESULTS
   ```

   It will create `FILTERED-RESULTS` folder with `HTTP Request` sampler only (or whatever else samplers, only `JSR223 Sampler`(s) will be excluded.

More information:

- [Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks, this should do it for me.